# Curvature tool questions

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Two Curvature Tool questions for Illustrator:

1. **How do you "end the drawing"?** `Enter` works for the Pen Tool but not the Curvature Tool. I've always just changed tools but that feels lame. Sometimes I'd like to start a new curve
2. Say I have a curve drawn with Curvature Tool that contains a corner (in the first picture below, I'm referring to the curve that is not selected). If I draw a second curve with the Curvature Tool (the active curve in the first picture), and then click the end of the first curve, it loses its corner (see second picture). **Why does clicking on the end of a curve remove its corner points, and can I stop that from happening?** See gif below for this issue in action.

I hope these both have straight-forward answers. I've googled around with no luck.

[image: Two curves, both with corners]
[image: Joined the curves, but the second lost its corner]

[image: gif of described behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press Escape, or close the path

[image]

2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click to create a corner points, or double click does the same

[image]

Comment: You answered #1 for me, thanks!  I think you didn't understand what I was getting at for #2. I added a gif in my q for clarity. I was trying to ask why under certain conditions corner points I've already made disappear.

Comment: @TimH - OK, I see that now. Thanks. I get that too - just some weird inexplicable glitch.  Illustrator is like that sometimes! Anyway, you can double click on the changed corner point to turn it back into a proper corner point.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've done that too sometimes but it's not nice when you lose more than a few corner points... I posted it on their issues forum [here](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-desktop-bugs/suggestions/44830828--corner-anchor-points-become-smooth-when-joining). Appreciate your help!